# Extension methods on an interface; delegates

Tags: c#, interface, delegates, extension-methods, event-handling

I'm trying to get around dual inheritance in C# by re-implementing one of the parent classes as an interface with extension methods.

The problem I'm encountering is that

```
event EventHandler<EventArgs> Disconnecting;

public static void OnDisconnected(this AutoConnectClientBase target)
        {
            target.ClientConnectionState = ConnectionState.Disconnected;
            target.Disconnected(target, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
```

Can't be called in the extension methods.
I get: ***.Disconnecting can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=
While this makes perfect sense, in this case I wish it were not so.

What I'm looking for is a workaround that will permit me to access my interface's EventHandlers in the extension code. I'd like to keep it as simple as possible since the class I'm making into an interface is accessed by a large number of classes already and this is a change I'm reluctantly making in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by doing the following:
Outside of the interface

```
public delegate EventHandler<EventArgs> MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

Then inside the interface

```
event EventHandler<EventArgs> Disconnecting;
```

becomes

```
MyEventHandler Connected {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the problem is here -- the code you show doesn't match the error you cite (no call to `.Disconnecting`.

```
public interface IInterface
{
    event EventHandler Event;
    EventHandler Handler { get; set; }
}

public class Class : IInterface
{
    public event EventHandler Event;
    public EventHandler Handler { get; set; }

}

public static class InterfaceExtensions
{
    public static void DoSomething(this IInterface i)
    {
        i.Event += (o, e) => Console.WriteLine("Event raised and handled");
        i.Handler(i, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jean So what in my code is different from what you want to do?

Comment: the "event EventHandler Event" will give a  compiler error when accessed from the extension method.

Comment: The code above gives no compiler error. You must, of course, declare the event as `public`.